# Facebook OG: Register achivement doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, web-services, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to register facebook open graph achivement, but It doens't work.

Get app access token like this:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

HTML page look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <meta property="og:type" content="game.achievement"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="URL/testAchivement.html"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="URL_TO_IMAGE"/>
    <meta property="game:points" content="10"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID"/>

    <title>ACHIEVEMENT!</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I use this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/achievements?achievement=MYSERVER/testAchivement.html&display_order=2&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and get this response:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

No errors when using facebook debug tool.

Please help , thanks!

Comment: Did you try just: https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/achievements?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN - does it return a list ?

Comment: Also does your URL so achievements following your game canvas URL ? 
    If you register an achievement URL of www.example.com/my_game/ach1.html, it will be rewritten to apps.facebook.com/my_game/ach1.html.
    If you register an achievement URL of www.example.com/achievements/ach1.html it will not be rewritten, because it is not a child of www.example.com/my_game/.